# Email from "research@stackoverflow.email"—is it legitimate?

Tags: support, email, email-verification

I've received an email from "research@stackoverflow.email". Is it legitimate? How can I tell?

I won't quote the whole thing, but in short it's asking for feedback for a new feature:

> .. We’re testing a new feature and we'd love to hear what you think of it...

It includes a *sign up for chat* "button" with a link that starts with `https://itr-links.stackoverflow.email...` and is 359 characters long.

edit:

Someone marked this question as a duplicate to [What email domains are known to be used by Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390598).
Why I don't think it's a duplicate:

1. My question is older so if they are duplicates, the other question should be closed against this one, rather than the other way around.
2. I was asking specifically if a concrete email address is legitimate, while the other question asks a general question about used domains.

Comment: Domain seems legit - that's one of the email domains they use as far as I remember

Comment: Legit but might be a bug in the sender address, all the emails I get are from do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email so that people won't reply.

Comment: To stop getting those emails, go to [your email settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current) and uncheck "Research" items.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack  It's not bout opting out as much as about legitimacy

Comment: the domain is indeed owned by Stack Overflow (and what they use for sending emails). If DKIM validation passes, it's sent by Stack Overflow. Also, the fact there's a subdomain is no cause for concern. It's sent using sendgrid and that's how clicks are tracked

Comment: @g3rv4 yes, they must have a way to gather the data to generate those nice graphs and presentations, e.g. "5421 users reached the Survey by clicking link in email".

Comment: @Greenmarty The email in question was from me, I'm a UX Researcher at Stack Overflow. We use a tool called Iterable to help us keep track of requests for participation in research studies. The "sign up to chat" would take you to a Calendly link to schedule a session!

Comment: @EmmaBee question is whether Greenmarty asked to get such emails or not.

Comment: Oh, I see where I went wrong. The emails are definitely legitimate. If Greenmarty wants to stop receiving them, they can simply adjust their email settings.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @EmmaBee I know this isn't your fault and is really industry standard - my employer does the same thing - but as a field y'all really have to figure out how to make less spammy legitimate emails. Emails with links feeding through trackers etc look exactly like illegitimate spam. Sender address is not sufficient validation because it's easily spoofed or routed through compromised accounts. Legit links should always go through friendly domains and/or have an alternative mechanism for access, like an inbox you get to through your normal login.

Comment: @Bryan if the DKIM validation passes, you know it's legit. I understand you may not like the tracking, but as you said... it _is_ industry standard

Comment: @g3rv4 servers can be hacked, so in theory the hackers can be sending from the actual servers of SE.

Comment: @Shadow yeah well, if you hack SE servers, you can control what happens to people landing on stackoverflow.com... in that scenario, hackers would probably send you to stackoverflow.com and do anything malicious there :)

Comment: @g3rv4 Doesn't help if the email account is compromised (like by a previous phish), and the domain in this case is not even one that we should generally trust, it's trivial for a bad actor to obtain a somedomain.other domain where people are familiar with somedomain.com.

Comment: I'd have marked anything coming from "@stackoverflow.email" as phishing without a second look. Mostly because of the sus looking domain. And tracking links being industry standard doesn't mean it's acceptable - basic security definitely isn't "industry standard", which is why phishing and related things still happen as much as they do.

Comment: @EmmaBee  Thanks for reaching out, that confirms it's from stackoverflow.

Comment: @ColeTobin  Partially yes. 
I needed to know whether this concrete email was legit.  
Of course, having some sort of list is also useful for future.

Comment: That the other question is older isn't a problem for duplicate closing. This happens more often, especially in cases like this: a specific question comes up, for which a canonical answer would also work. If that canonical has not been written, it has to be done, making it by necessity younger than the "original" question.

Comment: @Adriaan
 it doesn't answer my question thou.

Comment: And that's your second reason, which is a fine reason to disagree with the duplicate closure. My comment was merely to point out that your first argument is actually invalid.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That email address is at least valid. See [this post of mine on meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424730/5211833), about emails from that same address. [Emma Bee](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/21167450/emma-bee), a UX researcher at SO, [confirmed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424730/receiving-stack-overflow-emails-again-despite-opting-out#comment958015_424730) that those were indeed actual emails from SE.

<sub>They never got back about why those emails were sent to me in the first place, though, in direct violation of my email settings.</sub>

Comment: sorry to not get back to you about this. I did some digging, but could not find an issue. If your email settings are set as you prefer and it happens again, please email me directly and will look more into it!

Comment: @EmmaBee  i though about email you but i could not find your email so i posted question here. I don't click on unfamiliar links in email unless i know it can be trusted.

Answer (score 12):

As [Emma Bee](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1314236/emma-bee) mentioned in [a comment on your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390557/email-from-researchstackoverflow-email-is-it-legitimate/390560?noredirect=1#comment1304529_390557), this is indeed a legitimate email sent by Stack Overflow:

> The email in question was from me, I'm a UX Researcher at Stack Overflow. We use a tool called Iterable to help us keep track of requests for participation in research studies. The "sign up to chat" would take you to a Calendly link to schedule a session!